# How to get HWND for UI controls of Google Chrome in Metro mode

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-8, microsoft-metro, microsoft-ui-automation

I am trying to get access to UI controls of Google Chrome in Metro mode to get the current URL.

I have used the "Inspector" tool (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86\inspect.exe) to get HWND of Chrome in Desktop mode. It works fine, but when I tried to get access for Chrome in Metro mode it just display one global HWND without child windows.

For Google Chrome in Desktop mode I use the UI automation framework to get the URL:

```
        var element = AutomationElement.FromHandle(hWnd);

        if (element == null)
            return PageInfo.Empty;

        var addressBar = element.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants,
            new AndCondition(new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Address and search bar"),
                new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit)));

        if (addressBar == null)
            return PageInfo.Empty;

        var url = ((ValuePattern)addressBar.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern)).Current.Value;
```

Could you please help with getting the access of UI controls in Metro mode of Chrome?